# Using nm(1) to list symbols from object file built for arm64 on OS X

Tags: ios, macos, arm64, nm, otool

Does anyone know how can list symbols from an object file that I built for arm64 architecture?

I tried to use `nm` but it gave me an error:

```
bfd_mach_o_scan: unknown architecture0x100000c/0x0 
File format not recognized
```

Is it possible to do the same thing using `otool`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The system `nm` doesn't read arm64.  You need to use the `nm` that came with your arm64 SDK (i.e. the iphoneos SDK in Xcode).  This is the same path as where you ran `clang`.

```
$ xcrun -sdk iphoneos clang -arch arm64 main.c
$ xcrun -sdk iphoneos nm a.out 
0000000100000000 T __mh_execute_header
0000000100007f4c T _main
                 U _printf
                 U dyld_stub_binder
```

Comment: Thanks Josh - your answer helped a lot :)